# How can I give permission of particular child pages of books in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I have lots of books and its child pages but what I need to do is only permit user (general user/ANONYMOUS user) to see the first page of the book and the rest of the page should only be visible to particular person (authorized user). How can I achieve this in Drupal 7?

I have created a form in which I am giving option to assign user with the taxonomy term. I can't able to give permission for the viewing the book's child page.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) you can set permission on per node basis.

Cheers!!!

Comment: actually i got it wrong the actual requirement was diffrent, i need to assign diffrent/multiple taxonomy term(under this there can be many books) to diffrent users and only the assigned user have access of particular texonomy books. example suppose i have 2 texonomy 1st is engineering and onother one is science under that i have lots of books , so now if i have given permission to user for engineering taxonomy then he need to see all the books under this and  for scince books he can able to see the first page. please let me know the flow so that i can proceed with the module creation.

Comment: Taxonomy_access is not fit into my situation...btw thanks @prashant